# My Xamarin.ios BLE example "How to communicate with Bluetooth Low Energy devices on iOS" crashes

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I get a crash when I run the example code for a Bluetooth Low Energy app for Xamarin.ios
from blog "How to communicate with Bluetooth Low Energy devices on iOS" at:
https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-ios/how-to-communicate-with-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-on-ios

[image]

The zip for his example code is at:
https://github.com/wojciech-kulik/Sample-Projects

The only think I changed was to add his recommended NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription fix to my info.plist here................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>pl.wojciechkulik.BluetoothTest</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>9.3</string>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <!--for connecting to devices (client)-->
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>

        <!--for server configurations if needed-->
        <string>bluetooth-peripheral</string>
    </array>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 10, deprecated)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string>

    <!--Description of the Bluetooth request message (required on iOS 13)-->
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE</string></dict>
</plist>
```

STACK TRACE............

[image]

Comment: look at the stack trace to see what the cause of the null ref is

Comment: It doesn't show where in my code.  So, I'm now adding more try/catch throughout the code to isolate cause.

Comment: The property or instance of the BluetoothService and ViewController class may be null, try adding breakpoints to debug to check that.

Comment: Also, the problem is intermittant. At first, it would crash, then without any code changes, on Friday it was working, then on Monday same exact code, started crashing at every run again.